# How did the Joker time the Rachel explosion so precisely?

Tags: the-dark-knight

Given that the Joker doesn't have a clock in his cell, how did he time the explosion so precisely such that Batman will only have time to save one? If he told Batman 1 min later, Gordon would have saved Rachel too.

Comment: Trying to remember, but is there any indication that they are actually timed?  More likely there was someone watching each and told to detonate at a specific moment.

Comment: There's a timer attached to the bomb, but there's a phone as well, so it is hard to know if the bomb was indeed activated by the time running out or by the Joker himself calling the attached phone.

Comment: If there's one thing Joker (Jerome) understands, it's insurance for a plot. It's likely he had someone standing by to manually detonate the bombs, or a way to do it himself. Remember that Jerome (Like Bruce, as a counterpart) is also extremely smart and resourceful. If he wanted those explosions to time out right, he'd have figured out how. Yes this is partly speculation, hence why it's a comment and not an answer, to whomever is getting ready to flag it.

Comment: @MissouriSpartan where did the name Jerome came from?

Comment: @Vishwa Jack Napier is his name. I got him mixed up with Jerome Valeskia in Gotham.

Comment: Was Jack Napier ever mentioned in the Dark Knight series? I'm having very hard time remembering it

Comment: It's neither Jerome *nor* Jack, we don't *know* his name. The Joker from *The Dark Knight* has absolutely *zero* to do with Jack Napier.

Comment: This is a very old question, but I believe I have a different explanation. In the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ChPTKPzB4I at 1:06, we can see that Gordon's watch is visible on his left wrist. Immediately, we see the Joker take a peek down, as if he's looking at his watch. It may very well be intentional to get a peek of the current time.